# Do the hints for the final room of the Soultaker's Pit in Avernum 5 uniquely identify a solution?

Tags: avernum-5

In the Soultaker's Pit in Avernum 5, the final room (after you beat the Soultaker) contains four "stands", positioned at the northeast, northwest, southeast, and southwest corners of a pit. To raise the portcullises to the north and south, one must configure the orbs on the four stands correctly and then ring the gong.

Each stand can either have a red-sparkling orb, a blue-sparkling orb, a green-sparkling orb, a non-sparkling orb, or no orb at all.

To help the player determine the correct configuration of the orbs, there are hints scattered throughout the Soultaker's Pit (located on the walls; some of them are barely visible because lighting items scarcely work in the basement, and the color scheme is terrible for visibility). As far as I can tell, there are six hints:

- At least one stand to the north has no orb.
- A western orb has red sparkles.
- There are no blue sparkles.
- A sparkling orb to the north is not red.
- No sparkles are the same color.
- Two orbs are sparkling on the diagonal.

Now, I didn't want to sit here and muddle through this myself, so I wrote [a constraint solver](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d4b5ad99cb3b9522f5da) that gave me the following two solutions:

1. Northwest = no orb; Northeast = green orb; Southeast = **no orb**; Southwest = red orb
2. Northwest = no orb; Northeast = green orb; Southeast = **non-sparkling orb**; Southwest = red orb

And I should think that both of these solutions are compatible with the six hints. However, solution (1.) summons a banshee; only solution (2.) actually opens the portcullises.

Am I misinterpreting the hints? Or did I miss a seventh hint that eliminates (1.)? (Or are both solutions valid and the devs just didn't notice (1.)?)

Answer (score 2):

There was one more hint that you missed that lets you uniquely identify the one:

> At least one orb to the South doesn't sparkle.